# sqlite bit columns return 'false' value in every case

Tags: c#, android, database, sqlite

I am using the sqlite v3, i have the table which has some columns of data type 'bit'. I have inserted some data in this table with value 'true' in bit columns, But the problem is that when i retrieve the data using C# code it always return the value 'false'.

The same query and same database is working fine for my android application. But, when i retrieve these data from C# or windows, than it returns the unusual results.

Sqlite admin shows the correct result in query pane..... 
I am using chrome browser....
My C# code is

```
SQLiteConnection sqlite_connection =null;

        if(isTrans)
            sqlite_connection = sqliteTrans.Connection;
        else
            sqlite_connection = this.ConnectionInstance;

        try
        {  
            SQLiteCommand sqlite_command = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT AdditionalServices, VitalObservation from tblReadonlyPatientData where SubscriptionID = 1306", sqlite_connection);
            SQLiteDataReader reader = sqlite_command.ExecuteReader();
            StringBuilder queryToExecute = new StringBuilder();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                queryToExecute.Append(reader.GetString(0));
            }

            // always call Close when done reading. 
            reader.Close();
            reader = null;
            sqlite_command = null

        }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                clsException.ExceptionInstance.HandleException(e);
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (!isTrans && sqlite_connection != null)
                {
                    if (sqlite_connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                        sqlite_connection.Close();                    
                }
            }
```

These columns are the bit datatype and 'true' values but returns false.

Comment: Can you add 1- some sample records with the exact values in the bit column, and 2- the C# code use to retrieve the data?

Comment: Which column _exactly_ has the "bit" type and where are you using it with unexpected results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i have update the sql lite query and cast the bit columns into nvarchar, so it return me the string in 'true' or 'false' format

```
SQLiteCommand sqlite_command = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT Cast(AdditionalServices as nvarchar(10)) as AdditionalServices, Cast(VitalObservation as nvarchar(10)) as VitalObservation from tblReadonlyPatientData where SubscriptionID = 1306", sqlite_connection);
```

Comment: @Ludo actually the above solution which i posted helps me so, i want to share it with you.

Answer (score 1):

To sqlite, the string 'true' evaluates to False because sqlite casts the string to the type Numeric which returns 0 which is directly False:

```
sqlite> select cast('true' as numeric);
0
```

Taken from http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html:

> To convert the results of an SQL expression to a boolean value, SQLite
>   first casts the result to a NUMERIC value in the same way as a CAST
>   expression. A NULL or zero value (integer value 0 or real value 0.0)
>   is considered to be false. All other values are considered true.

So I recommend you change your true/false column to a numeric type and store 1 for True and 0 for False.

Comment: You are absolutely right but the problem is that we have to change it in our large project, but the same thing is working fine on android devices. Can you come with some other alternate solution, so i have to do the minimum change... thanks

Comment: Please post the C# code you are using as it should give a better idea of what is really happening in your situation.

Comment: actually the above solution which i posted helps me so, i want to share it with you.